# can't locate object method "see" via package "Net::IMAP::Simple"

Tags: perl, imap

I am trying to fetch unread emails from server and mark them as seen (read) after fetching. I'm using perl script and the package Net::IMAP::Simple. I'm writing this script for the office work.

Below is some code :

```
use strict;    
use warnings;
use Net::IMAP::Simple;
use Email::Simple;
use HTTP::Date;
#some code....

# Create the object
my $server = Net::IMAP::Simple->new($imap_server) or die "Can't connect to server: $imap_server ";

# Log on
my $login = $server->login($imap_user,$imap_passwd) or die "Login failed (bad username or password)";

#some code.....

# set the message as seen
$server->see($i);

# i also used $server->add_flags($i,'\Seen'); but it throws same error.
```

The Irony is, this code works fine on my Gmail account , which i use for testing. but when i test it in office it throws error ;

can't locate object method "see" via package "Net::IMAP::Simple"

I don't know what's the issue here.

Comment: What does `perl -MNet::IMAP::Simple -E 'say $Net::IMAP::Simple::VERSION'` print?

Comment: @dada: right now i don't have access to system (on my phone). will check for sure. but can you tell me details? like what it should print and what would it mean?

Comment: @dada is probably right. It looks like you have an outdated version of  Net::IMAP::Simple. You can also just do `perl -MNet::IMAP::Simple\ 999` to get the version (as an error message).

Comment: If you have the latest version of `Net::IMAP::Simple`, it should print `1.2207`. After a quick look at the previous versions of the module, it seems that the `see` method wasn't always there. So if you have an outdated version of the module, it would make sense that you can call the method.

Comment: @Dada I took the liberty to write that up. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: @ simbabque & dada : sure guys. I guess so too. will check and get back to you.

Comment: @dada : bro ,i'm having hard time trying to retrieve the body of the mail. can you tell me how can i retrieve only the mail body using Net::IMAP::Client?

Comment: @simbabque I don't mind at all; on the contrary, I wasn't too sure on which version the `see` method had been added, so I was hoping that someone would post an answer with the details :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The methods [`see`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Net-IMAP-Simple/Simple.pod#see) and [`unsee`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Net-IMAP-Simple/Simple.pod#unsee) were added in [Net::IMAP::Simple version 1.1899_05](https://metacpan.org/changes/distribution/Net-IMAP-Simple#L391).

```
> 1.1899_05: Tue Jun 16 06:42:16 EDT 2009
>    - I started working on ticket 45953,
>    - created sub_flags() and add_flags()
>    - taught delete() to use add_flags() -- adds \Deleted
>    - providing see() and unsee() for ticket 45953
>    - I started building tests for the flag manipulation stuff and
>      put reselect stuff ... noticed a possible bug in
>      Net::IMAP::Server
```

You likely have an older version on your production system. Update it, and include a minimum version in your Makefile.PL or cpanfile or whatever you use to track dependencies.

Comment: sure buddy. anyways , i'm having hard time retrieving the body of the mail. can you tell me how can i retrieve only the mail body using Net::IMAP::Client?

Comment: @RaJ sorry, I've never used that thing before. I'm just good at reading documentation. ;) Please ask a new question for that.

Comment: where can i download the package  Net::IMAP::Simple version 1.1899_05. I can apt or yum or rpm through command line in linux. so i want to manually download it and place it in a separate folder.

Comment: @RaJ you could just install it from CPAN, or build it yourself. I don't know where you would get a system package for your OS. If you just install the newest version from CPAN you should be fine. `cpan NET::IMAP::Simple` or similar.